# declarativeNetRequest modifyHeaders issue for safari extension. Header is not recognized

Tags: safari, safari-extension, chrome-declarativenetrequest

Declarative net Request modify header rule is not working for safari. Works fine on all other browsers (chrome, edge , FF etc)

Safari Version 16.5.2 (18615.2.9.11.10)

manifest rule: "declarativeNetRequestWithHostAccess"

Error: [Error] Error: Invalid call to declarativeNetRequest.updateDynamicRules(). Error with rule at index 0: Rule with id 100 is invalid. The header `x-source` is not recognized.

However, if I change the header name to "Origin" it works. Is there a restriction on which all header names are supported?

await browser.declarativeNetRequest.updateDynamicRules({ addRules: x });

var x = [{
"id": 100,
"priority": 1,
"action": {
"type": "modifyHeaders",
"requestHeaders": [
{
"header": "x-source",
"operation": "set",
"value": "test"
}
]
},
"condition": {
"urlFilter": "https://*/*"
}
}]

Comment: Adding details about Safari version would help since Safari 16.4 release added a lot of new APIs for 'declarativeNetRequest'.